# Why doesn't this Ruby on Rails code work as I intend it to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, voting

So I attempted to build what I asked about in this question: [Fix voting mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356084/fix-voting-mechanism)

However, this solution doesn't work. A user can still vote however many times he or she wants. How could I fix this and/or refactor?

```
def create       
    @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @vote = @video.video_votes.new
    @vote.user = current_user

    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end

  if @previous_vote.nil?
    if @vote.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @video }
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @video }
        format.js {render 'fail_create.js.erb'}
      end
    end
  elsif @previous_vote.value == params[:type]
    @previous_vote.destroy
  else
    @previous_vote.destroy    
    if @vote.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @video }
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @video }
        format.js {render 'fail_create.js.erb'}
      end
    end
  end
  @previous_vote = VideoVote.where(:video_id => params[:video_id], :user_id => current_user.id).first
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@previous_vote` seems to be nil at the beginning of every request?

I would personally do away with all the logic in the controller and put uniqueness contraints at Model or database level where they belong.

**Updated**

*This is probably full of errors but treat it as pseudo-code*

Models something like:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :video_id # only one vote per person per video
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
end
```

Controller:

```
def create
  @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
  @vote = current_user.votes.find_or_create_by_video_id(@video.id)

  # change this next block of code so you assign value to the vote based on whatever logic you need
  if you_need_to_do_anything_to_change_its_value
    @vote.value = :whatever
  end

  if @vote.save
    redirect_to @video
  else
    render :whatever_is_appropriate
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the reason it's nil? And why move it to the model? And how would the code look in the model?

Comment: if the vote fails the validation, will it fail silently? Also, when is the validation run? When I try to save the vote into the database?

Comment: if the vote fails `@vote.save` will return false `@vote.save!` would raise an Exception. The validation will run during the transaction triggered by calling `save`. You can find the callback structure of ActiveRecord here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your controller code. What exactly is this line: `@vote = current_user.votes.find_or_create_by_video_id(@video.id)`? Do I need an if statement for it? Also, how can I change the value of the vote if it's the create method and not an update method?

Comment: I'm assuming that current_user is set before hand of course. That line is a dynamic finder provided by ActiveRecord. It will find an existing vote or create a new one. Then the subsequent lines of code can modify value before you save the vote again. I've added a comment above.

Comment: ahhh, I didn't know find_or_create_<attribute> existed! I thought it was a filler call that you made haha.

Comment: In the block of code where I change the value, how do I know whether `@vote` was found or created? I feel like I would need to know this so I can delete the old vote if a vote was found...

Comment: I would add a unique index by user and video in the video_votes table - that would fully eliminate any chances of having a user having multiple votes for the same video. The #validates_uniqueness_of validation is nice, but there's still a race condition.

Comment: @Francois Yes my video_votes table has a unique user_id and video_id already.