# Why doesn't this Ruby on Rails voting code work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, voting

So I really thought this would work to create the voting system like we have here on SO:

```
def create       
  @video = Video.find(params[:video_id])
  @vote = current_user.video_votes.find_or_create_by_video_id(@video.id)

  if @vote.value.nil?
    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end
  elsif (params[:type] == "up" && @vote.value == 1) || (params[:type] == "down" && @vote.value == -1)
    @vote.value = 0
  elsif ((params[:type] == "up" && @vote.value == -1) || (params[:type] == "down" && @vote.value == 1)) || (@vote.value == 0)
    if params[:type] == "up"
      @vote.value = 1
    else
      @vote.value = -1
    end
  end  

  if @vote.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @video }
      format.js {render 'fail_create.js.erb'}
    end
  end   
end
```

I tried to follow the example of the first answer in this question: [Why doesn't this Ruby on Rails code work as I intend it to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360914/why-doesnt-this-ruby-on-rails-code-work-as-i-intend-it-to) My code, however, doesn't let me vote on a video for the first time because of this error:

```
TypeError (nil can't be coerced into Fixnum):
app/models/video_vote.rb:11:in `update_vote_sum'
app/controllers/video_votes_controller.rb:4:in `create
```

Here's my videovote model:

```
class VideoVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :video_id

  after_create :update_vote_sum

  private

    def update_vote_sum
      video.update_attributes!(:vote_sum => video.vote_sum + value)
    end
end
```

And in case this is needed, here's my `vote_sum` method from my Video model:

```
def vote_sum
  video_votes.sum(:value)
end
```

Comment: Looks like your error is in your vote model so you should show us `vote.rb`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this Ruby on Rails code work as I intend it to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360914/why-doesnt-this-ruby-on-rails-code-work-as-i-intend-it-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `after_create` method in `VideoVote.rb`, you're summing over all votes, including the one you've just created with a nil value. Switch `after_create` to `after_update`, or set a default for `value` on `VideoVote`.

In looking at that, if `vote_sum` is calling `sum` on all of your votes every time anyways, you probably don't even need an `after_create` or `after_update` method if votes have a default value set.

--

You could also replace this entire system with the [thumbs_up](https://github.com/brady8/thumbs_up) gem, and save yourself some hassle.

Comment: Thumbs up gem might be the way to go.

Comment: still have the same error... I kinda want to implement it myself :)

Comment: As is often the case in Rails work, convention over configuration. Why reinvent the wheel when voting and karma are already handled pretty well :) Implementing yourself can always be fun though.

Comment: I feel like there would be some overhead for me to understand how to use the plugin. I also wouldn't understand how it works internally, while I think I'm almost already done with implementing it on my own.

Comment: sweet, thanks!!! I'm kinda proud that a figured out the logic behind the create method :) I just started programming a month ago.

Comment: by the way, do you mean I can get rid of the `update_vote_sum` method as well?

Comment: Glad it worked! Yes, I believe you can remove your `update_vote_sum` method. re: understanding other gems: There is always overhead to learning and using someone else's library, but it often comes with the benefit of (hopefully!) stable, secure and well-tested code that makes your actual application logic simpler and easier to enhance in the future. Congratulations on getting your implementation working! It's always a good feeling :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here. `vote_sum` is a method that sums up the number of votes that a video has, from what I can see, so why are you trying to update it as an attribute? It will always return the correct score of a video, you shouldn't need to manually update it, since it is not an attribute, but a calculated result of a method.